# Answering then editing

Tags: support, answers

I answered [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/god-imputes-sin) question and then went to correct the formatting but the option to edit had been greyed out? Is this a bug? Is it intentional and if so why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because there is an edit pending review. Until the edit is either accepted or rejected, further edits cannot be made.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you Flimzy.

Comment: You mean further edits requiring review (from low rep users), or does this include edits from high rep users?

Comment: @fredsbend: Only one pending edit is possible at a time. That includes high-rep users. There is one way around that, if you are a high-rep user, you can review the pending edit then 'Improve' it rather than 'Accepting' it. This allows you to make your own edit, which then is applied immediately, rather than awaiting further approval votes. I'm not sure if that's by design or not, though.